# How to remove Phone number from Excel?

Tags: python, excel, automation

Please help me to remove the Phone number inside the string.  I have a excel file which has lots of description. I want to Remove the pHone numbers from those.

Description:

Hi,
Shared accommodation is available in Lombard-IL. Single bed room and I preferred Veggie only.
Please reach 630 828 3324 if any one interested.
Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import openpyxl
import re

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'pathtoexcel')

ph_no=r"\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}"

for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    max_col_val = ws.max_column
    max_row_val = ws.max_row
    for cols in range(1,max_col_val + 1):
        for rows in range(1,max_col_val):
            if (ws.cell(rows, cols).value)!=None:
                cl=ws.cell(rows, cols).value
                if re.findall(ph_no, cl):
                    cl=re.sub(ph_no,"",cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Description':['This is my mobile number 213 321 32111',
                                'another number 123 321 321',
                                'Hi, Shared accommodation is available in Lombard-IL. Single bed room and I preferred Veggie only. Please reach 630 828 3324 if any one interested. Thanks, Mohan']})
for i in range (len(df['Description'])):
    print(re.sub(" \d+", " ",df.loc[i,"Description"]))
```

This code will ignore all the numbers from your description.

Comment: BabuHi Thank you so much.   Can you please tell me.